# Getting the Default Workflow User's Email Signature in a Send Email Flow Action coming from an Org Wide Email Address

Tags: visual-workflow, send-email

I have a scheduled flow that is sending an email using the Send Email Flow Action instead of an email alert. When the email is delivered I am receiving the Default Workflow User's email signature that is listed in their personal email settings. Is there a way to have this removed?

Answer (score 0):

check this link https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5

You can change the sender's email address by configuring `Sender Type` and `Sender Email Address`. However, you should remember that if FLOW is called by a guest user, you should use OrgWideEmailAdress